# PHP - Regex works inconsistently

Tags: php, regex

I have the following statement

```
echo preg_replace("/(?<=\d)(th|rd|st|nd)([^0-z])/i","<sup>$1</sup>$2","some text 1st<br />\n2nd<br />\n3rd<br />\n4th 5th 21nd 33rd 41st<br />\nsome text");
```

and it outputs

```
some text 1st<br />
2nd<br />
3rd<br />
4<sup>th</sup> 5<sup>th</sup> 21<sup>nd</sup> 33<sup>rd</sup> 41st<br />
some text
```

I just can't figure out how to make it surround th, rd, st or nd with with superscript tags in all cases.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use

```
/(?:\b\d+)(th|rd|st|nd)\b/i

//boundary \b is required here or else it would also replace within a word
```

and replace it with

```
<sup>$1</sup>
```

Comment: actually, with \b doesn't work on the last two lines, but without \b works great, even when text includes words like first fourth etc

Comment: @L84 use the regex that suits your needs..it worked in `.net` for me..;)

Comment: The first `\b` breaks it if there's more than one digit (`21st`, `33rd`, etc.).  In .NET you can just add a quantifier -- `(?<=\b\d+)` -- but that won't work in PHP.  The solution is not to use a lookbehind; simply replace `'/(\b\d+)(th|rd|st|nd)\b/i'` with `'$1<sup>$2</sup>'`.

Answer (score 0):

`[0-z]` also includes the following symbols: `` :;<=>?@[]^_` ``

Notably, `<` is included.

Try `[^[:alnum:]]` instead.

EDIT: Additionally, why not make it a lookahead?

```
/(?<=\d)(?:th|rd|st|nd)(?=![[:alnum:]])/i
```

Then you can just use `$0` in the replacement string.